# How to share data with Collection View delegates in View Controller Class in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, oop, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm having some trouble with how a protocol function for a CollectionView operates in a ViewController class. My problem is I have a class with with IDs that returns type string.

```
public class GroupIds {

var groupIds = [String]()

func setId(groups: [String])
{
    groupIds=groups
}
func getIds() -> [String]
{
return groupIds
}
```

I have a static variable that creates the GroupId object

```
  static var GI = GroupIds()
```

I have this public class which I access from my ViewController to set IDs. In a function in my ViewController I create and set them like so:

```
 func setId()
 {
 GroupViewController.GI = GroupIds()
 GroupViewController.GI.setId(groups: self.getGroupIds(groups: groups))
 }
```

In another function I access these IDs and I get the **correct** response. I do that like this:

```
   @IBAction func testButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(GroupViewController.GI.getIds())
}
```

However my problem is when I want to use the Ids in CollectionView delegate the data is always nil. This is my attempt:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(GroupViewController.GI.getIds())

    return GroupViewController.GI.getIds().count
}
```

When my collection view loads and this function is called it prints an empty array and returns 0. 
My question is how can I can make the numberOfItemsInSection function to behave like the testButton and see the values I have stored in the public class GroupIds.

Answer (score 1):

When do you call `setId()` in your main view controller? It seems to me that your data source is being set before your `setId()` method is called.

Maybe you can refresh the collectionView once your groups have been set in `setId()`

```
func setId() {
    GroupViewController.GI = GroupIds()
    GroupViewController.GI.setId(groups: self.getGroupIds(groups: groups))
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```